# Scala partition sorted list elements based on distance

Tags: scala, list

I am new to Scala and functional programming. I have a task that I want to partition a Scala list into list of sub-lists where the distance between each element in any sub-list is less than 2. I found a code somewhere online can do this but I don't understand how this code works internally, can someone give a detailed explanation?

```
    def partition(input: List[Int], prev: Int, 
    splits: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {
  input match {
    case Nil => splits
    case h :: t if h-prev < 2 => partition(t, h, (h :: splits.head) :: splits.tail)
    case h :: t => partition(t, h, List(h) :: splits)
  }
}


val input = List(1,2,3,5,6,7,10)
partition(input,input.head,List(List.empty[Int]))
```

The result is as follows:

List[List[Int]] = List(List(10), List(7, 6, 5), List(3, 2, 1))

which is the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes the original list is ordered from smallest to largest

it works recursively where in each call the input is what is still left of the list, prev holds the previous head of the list (input.head) and splits holds the splits so far

in each call, we look at the input (what's left of the list)

- if it is empty (Nil) we finished the split and we return the splits
- the other two options the match uses pattern matching to
  break the input into header and tail (h and t respectively)
- the second match uses a guard condition (the if) to check if the head of the input belongs in the latest split if it does it prepends it to the split
- the last option is to create a new split

Answer (score 1):

```
def partition(input  :List[Int]       // a sorted List of Ints
             ,prev   :Int             // Int previously added to the accumulator
             ,splits :List[List[Int]] // accumulator of Ints for eventual output
             ): List[List[Int]] = {   // the output (same type as accumulator)

  input match {         // what does input look like?
    case Nil => splits  // input is empty, return the accumulator

    // input has a head and tail, head is close to previous Int
    case h :: t if h-prev < 2 =>
      // start again with new input (current tail), new previous (current head),
      // and the current head inserted into accumulator
      partition(t, h, (h :: splits.head) :: splits.tail)

    // input has a head and tail, head is not close to previous Int
    case h :: t => 
      // start again with new input (current tail), new previous (current head),
      // and the current head is the start of a new sub-list in the accumulator
      partition(t, h, List(h) :: splits)
  }
}
```